# Link JS to wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

How do I make this work in Wordpress? I've been trying to link it together but it doesn't seem to work. Is it done this way or am I missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/js/sticky.js">
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/652/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your scripts in your function.php file, with wp_enqueue_script : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script